# atom is throwing error at the time of building

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, atom-editor

I am using ubuntu and trying to build it from source as described [here](https://flight-manual.atom.io/hacking-atom/sections/hacking-on-atom-core/#platform-linux)
but at the time of building it is showing me the error. I am following the steps mentioned in the official docs but still getting this error.

```
/atom$ script/bootstrap 
Node:   v16.13.0
Python: v3.9.5
Installing script dependencies
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ayondip/All_projects/web-3.0/atom/script/node_modules/fs-admin
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:10:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at step (/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:71:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at subStep (/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:33)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.11.0-41-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node" "/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/ayondip/All_projects/web-3.0/atom/script/node_modules/fs-admin
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ayondip/.npm/_logs/2022-01-11T04_02_56_141Z-debug.log
node:child_process:867
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: npm --loglevel=error install
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/ayondip/All_projects/web-3.0/atom/script/node_modules/fs-admin
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:10:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:57:18
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at step (/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:54:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:71:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at subStep (/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:33)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:22
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at /home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.11.0-41-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node" "/home/ayondip/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/ayondip/All_projects/web-3.0/atom/script/node_modules/fs-admin
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ayondip/.npm/_logs/2022-01-11T04_02_56_141Z-debug.log

    at checkExecSyncError (node:child_process:826:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:864:15)
    at module.exports (/home/ayondip/All_projects/web-3.0/atom/script/lib/install-script-dependencies.js:13:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ayondip/All_projects/web-3.0/atom/script/bootstrap:37:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [
    null,
    Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
    Buffer(1987) [Uint8Array] [
      110, 112, 109,  32,  69,  82,  82,  33,  32,  99, 111, 100,
      101,  32,  49,  10, 110, 112, 109,  32,  69,  82,  82,  33,
       32, 112,  97, 116, 104,  32,  47, 104, 111, 109, 101,  47,
       97, 121, 111, 110, 100, 105, 112,  47,  65, 108, 108,  95,
      112, 114, 111, 106, 101,  99, 116, 115,  47, 119, 101,  98,
       45,  51,  46,  48,  47,  97, 116, 111, 109,  47, 115,  99,
      114, 105, 112, 116,  47, 110, 111, 100, 101,  95, 109, 111,
      100, 117, 108, 101, 115,  47, 102, 115,  45,  97, 100, 109,
      105, 110,  10, 110,
      ... 1887 more items
    ]
  ],
  pid: 9438,
  stdout: Buffer(0) [Uint8Array] [],
  stderr: Buffer(1987) [Uint8Array] [
    110, 112, 109,  32,  69,  82,  82,  33,  32,  99, 111, 100,
    101,  32,  49,  10, 110, 112, 109,  32,  69,  82,  82,  33,
     32, 112,  97, 116, 104,  32,  47, 104, 111, 109, 101,  47,
     97, 121, 111, 110, 100, 105, 112,  47,  65, 108, 108,  95,
    112, 114, 111, 106, 101,  99, 116, 115,  47, 119, 101,  98,
     45,  51,  46,  48,  47,  97, 116, 111, 109,  47, 115,  99,
    114, 105, 112, 116,  47, 110, 111, 100, 101,  95, 109, 111,
    100, 117, 108, 101, 115,  47, 102, 115,  45,  97, 100, 109,
    105, 110,  10, 110,
    ... 1887 more items
  ]
}
```

can anyone help me out with  how to build atom from source code and why I am getting this error ?

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved. Find more details in the link.
https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/23471